# Copy a link if cell value matches entry in another list

Tags: vba, excel

There is a column with blocks of file names, and there is a column with keys and values:

[image: First and second lists]

I have to assign the link "www.111.com" to all AAAAA.jpg areas, "www.222.com" to BBBBB.jpg areas, etc.

Result:

[image]

How can be this done?

Comment: In your column C, you could do `=hyperlink(B1,A1)`?

Comment: yes but on the second list I have single values, that have to be used to fill first list. I think I have to compare values from column A (from the 1st list) to values  from column A (from the 2nd list) and give it hyperlink from column B (from 2nd list) if they're equal. But I dont know how to do it using vbs

Comment: Ahh, then I think you could just use a `vlookup()` to match the URL from your second list.  In your first list, b1, it'd be something like `=hyperlink(vlookup(a1,Sheet2!A1:B3,2),A1)`. I think that should work.

Comment: thanks, I understand this... But can I do this on the same column? or save values with hyperlinks, but delete =hyperlink(vlookup(a1,Sheet2!A1:B3,2),A1)? I need only one column with links

Comment: OP, can't you hide the input column? If not, VBA could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following VBA code will help you.  It does these steps:

1. Declare a range ("myRange") and set it to cell A1 (the top cell of your list of .JPGs)
2. Declare a variant ("hText")
3. Lookup the value in "myRange" in the lookup table at D:E (change to suit your workbook).  Store the value in "hText"
4. Check if hText is an error (i.e., the value was not found in the lookup table). If it was as error, skip the cell.  If it wasn't an error, go to step 5.
5. Add a hyperlink to the current "myRange" cell. Use the hText as the address, use the text of the current "myRange" cell as the displayed text.
6. Move "myRange" to the next cell down. Loop steps 3-6 until it reaches an empty cell.

Note that the loop will stop when it reaches an empty cell, so if there is a gap in your list it will not reach the bottom.  Also, note that any values that are not found in the lookup table will be skipped (no hyperlink added).

Run this code while the sheet with the list of .JPGs is selected.

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("A1")

Dim hText As Variant

Do Until IsEmpty(myRange)

    hText = Application.VLookup(myRange.Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:E"), 2, False)

    If IsError(hText) Then
        hText = ""
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myRange, Address:=hText, TextToDisplay:=myRange.Text
        hText = ""
    End If

    Set myRange = myRange.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, almost done)) This script is giving link file:///C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\www.111.com  instead of www.111.com... Maybe I have to change something?

Comment: @ZeroEight Sorry, I wasn't sure what format your links were in since the example data (I assumed) wasn't your actual link text (e.g., www dot one one one dot com). Excel can hyperlink to files or the internet, so you'll need http(s) to tell it to look on the interwebs instead of a location on your computer

Comment: Oh I've got another problem. If I have more than 100k links. Will i get a problem with number of links per document? How can i give 1 link for All AAAAA.jpg area?

Comment: @ZeroEight I'm not sure you can get around the maximum hyperlinks limit. That would be worth some looking into, and possibly a new question on SO if there isn't an answer or workaround, sorry